# Where should the attribute gridster-item be inserted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, gridster

I try inserting the gridster-item attribute in the following way:

```
<div class="myTile" gridster-item= "tile" row="0" col="0" ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles" > 
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
     <li><a href="#"
                id="gridster-form"
                role="button"
                aria-labeledby="Gridster Layout Form">

                 <span class="dropdown-text">
                    Col <input type="text" value="tile.col" integer ng-model="tile.col" size="1" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                    Row <input type="text" value="tile.row" integer ng-model="tile.row" size="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">     
                </span>
                <i class= "fa fa-arrows"></i>
    </a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Basically when I put in gridster-item, the input fields are correctly occupied by the tile.col and tile.row properties (without it they do not show up).

**THE PROBLEM** When I insert the gridster-item attribute it throws my tile in a random spot on the dom. This tells me im not using it right. Any suggestions?

Comment: Wouldn't that be related to you specifically setting the `row` and `col` to 0?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use an outher div and put ng-repeat on that:

```
<div ng-repeat="tile in selectedTiles"> 
    <div class="myTile" gridster-item= "tile" row="0" col="0"  > 
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
         <li><a href="#"
                    id="gridster-form"
                    role="button"
                    aria-labeledby="Gridster Layout Form">

                     <span class="dropdown-text">
                        Col <input type="text" value="tile.col" integer ng-model="tile.col" size="1" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
                        Row <input type="text" value="tile.row" integer ng-model="tile.row" size="1" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">     
                    </span>
                    <i class= "fa fa-arrows"></i>
        </a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```